# Google Maps Places Details request (PHP)

Tags: php, google-places-api

I read so many messages with that REQUEST_DENIED error but I still couldn't figure out why it's not working! My google API key has Places and Gmap v3 services activated. The key is working since my Autocomplete app is working with it. I'm also using the same domain as my Autocomplete app. I'm trying to check a place's details with its reference.

To spare you all my attempts, let's say I use [this class](https://github.com/anthony-mills/Google-Places---PHP-/blob/master/googlePlaces.php) and here is my code:

```
require('googlePlaces.php');
$g = new googlePlaces("MyGoogleAPIKey");
$g->setLanguage("fr");
$g->setReference($_GET['ref']);
var_dump( $g->details() );
```

But I kinda doubt that this is a code problem, since when I type the URL in the browser it should work, no?

When I echo the `$URLToCall` I have [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MyGoogleAPIKey&reference=CnRkAAAANb8Z2hdES4A-wCyX85rat4azuvIsqe7xpzIKQ-LSZO6N9OmweZtfkNazlIBdv28raT1_Q0l4XfdvCg6NzhWstSbKPKOh65XLQl2w5Y1gjMBs-Z_9NpiCemu6LQOxZD8oWfsj_lg20KT10XL9TZwVaRIQfH8Pu4Y6Yq0VQKQICPgY6hoU44ilRNmPXsWOLabYoqzE09WWrGc&language=fr&sensor=false). And that URL in a browser give me a REQUEST_DENIED.

I'm lost :(

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You have used a real API key, haven't you?

Comment: Just for my knowledge, should I get a correct response by pasting the url in the browser or is it normal that it fails?

Comment: +1 to doobdargent's suggestion. Log the $URLToCall variable in _apiCall() and paste the URL into a browser. If it fails, include the URL in your question (minus API key) and there should be a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok folks, I kind of hate myself.
I lost 2 days trying to figure out what was going wrong.

For I don't know what reasons, I had to create a new project and get a new API key.